# How to use s3 bucket images on wordpress media library without plugin

Tags: plugins, php, amazon

For a week i am trying to find a solution to connect my aws s3 with wordpress site. Best solution for me was using plugins which built to handle this but I am using ***docker container***, even there's no settings in wp-config or docker environment all plugins says ***you have a conflict for aws s3 settings in your wp-config(plugins such as wp-offload media)***. So I decided to handle it by myself.

I created a php page which i can see images in my s3 bucket, upload new images and delete images. Its working very well. My goal is upload the images to s3 bucket, see them in library and use them in wordpress media selection in pages.

For now, i am able to upload, see the images in carousel i created, get the url and put into wp direction so i can see the image in media library with s3 URL, delete the image. My problem is when i go to page settings and click on media library, that image doesn't show up.

Have no idea if thats the best solution or how to handle that. Here is my code;

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: S3 Image Gallery
*/

// Include the AWS SDK for PHP
include realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

// Replace these with your AWS credentials and bucket name
$aws_access_key = 'key';
$aws_secret_key = 'secret';
$bucket_name = 'bucketname';
$aws_region = 'region';

// Instantiate the S3Client
$s3_client = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => $aws_region,
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => $aws_access_key,
        'secret' => $aws_secret_key,
    ],
]);

// Function to get the list of objects in the S3 bucket
function get_s3_objects() {
    global $s3_client, $bucket_name;
    try {
        $objects = $s3_client->listObjects([
            'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
        ]);

        return $objects['Contents'];
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        // Handle the exception, e.g., display an error message
        return [];
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>S3 Bucket Gallery</title>
    <style>
        /* Add CSS styles for the gallery layout */
        .gallery-carousel {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }
        .gallery-item {
            width: 140px;
            height: 140px;
            margin: 5px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        .gallery-item img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
        /* Add CSS styles for the carousel */
        .slick-slide {
            margin: 0 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Add Slick Carousel CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Wrapper for the carousel -->
    <div class="gallery-carousel">
        <?php
        // Get the list of objects in the S3 bucket
        $objects = get_s3_objects();

        // Loop through the objects and display images in the gallery
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            $image_url = $s3_client->getObjectUrl($bucket_name, $object['Key']);
            echo '<div class="gallery-item"><img src="' . $image_url . '" alt="Image"></div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Form to upload new image -->
    <div>
        <h2>Upload New Image</h2>
        <form action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image_file">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Add Slick Carousel JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Initialize the Slick Carousel on the gallery-carousel element
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.gallery-carousel').slick({
                infinite: true,
                slidesToShow: 4, // Set the number of slides to show at once
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev">Previous</button>',
                nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next">Next</button>',
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

<?php
// Function to upload an image to the S3 bucket
function upload_to_s3($file) {
    global $s3_client, $bucket_name;
    try {
        $object_key = basename($file['name']);
        $s3_client->putObject([
            'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
            'Key' => $object_key,
            'SourceFile' => $file['tmp_name'],
        ]);

        // Get the URL of the uploaded image
        $image_url = $s3_client->getObjectUrl($bucket_name, $object_key);
        return $image_url;
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        // Handle the exception, e.g., display an error message
        return false;
    }
}

// Handle image upload if a file is submitted
if (isset($_FILES['image_file']) && $_FILES['image_file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $uploaded_url = upload_to_s3($_FILES['image_file']);
    if ($uploaded_url) {
        // Image uploaded successfully, display the URL
        echo '<p>Image uploaded successfully. URL: <a href="' . $uploaded_url . '">' . $uploaded_url . '</a></p>';
    } else {
        // Image upload failed, display an error message
        echo '<p>Image upload failed.</p>';
    }
}

// Function to delete an image from the S3 bucket
function delete_from_s3($object_key) {
    global $s3_client, $bucket_name;
    try {
        $s3_client->deleteObject([
            'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
            'Key' => $object_key,
        ]);
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        // Handle the exception, e.g., display an error message
    }
}

// Handle image upload if a file is submitted
if (isset($_FILES['image_file']) && $_FILES['image_file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    upload_to_s3($_FILES['image_file']);
}

// Handle image deletion if a key is passed via GET parameter
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    delete_from_s3($_GET['delete']);
}
?>
```

function in functions.php

```
function insert_s3_image_to_db($image_url) {
    // Check if the file exists on the S3 bucket
    if (get_headers($image_url)[0] === 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
        // Fetch the title from the S3 URL
        $title = sanitize_file_name(basename(parse_url($image_url, PHP_URL_PATH)));

        // Get the file size using the S3 URL headers
        $headers = get_headers($image_url, true);
        $file_size = isset($headers['Content-Length']) ? (int) $headers['Content-Length'] : 0;

        // Prepare the attachment data
        $attachment_data = array(
            'guid'           => $image_url, // Set the S3 URL as the GUID
            'post_mime_type' => 'image', // You can also get the mime type from S3 if available
            'post_title'     => $title, // Use the title as the file name
            'post_content'   => '',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit'
        );

        // Set a custom attachment ID to prevent WordPress from modifying the GUID
        $custom_attachment_id = time(); // Use any unique value for the attachment ID

        // Insert the attachment into the WordPress database
        $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment_data, '', $custom_attachment_id);

        if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
            // Generate the metadata for the attachment
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
            $attachment_metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $image_url);
            $attachment_metadata['file_size'] = $file_size;
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_url);
            $attachment_metadata['width'] = $width;
            $attachment_metadata['height'] = $height;
            wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_metadata);
        }
    }
}
```